# Creating odd shapes

Tags: adobe-illustrator

In Illustrator I'm creating a logo to go in the top corner of a greater image.
This logo is to feature as part of it a line across the top. The trouble is I want the edges of the top of my image to be curved. The lines however go over the top of the background shape and stick out.

Is there any way to make this background shape act somewhat akin to an artboard? Anything that goes on top of it exists only on top of it and doesn't overflow.

Comment: try adding a clipping mask?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could show us some screenshots.  Are you talking about an issue in Illustrator only?

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

1. Create a shape
2. Then select it and the items you want to be included
3. Right click and select <kbd>Create clipping mask</kbd>

This should clip to the shape and hide any overflow.